# FB pixel custom property value _removed_ in facebook events

Tags: javascript, facebook

Facebook pixel trakkingcode 
Standard events are handed over and personalized events are removed. Is there a solution for the transfer of personalized events?

```
 fbq('track', 'ViewMagazin', {
                               content_type: 'Magazin',
                               category: 'categories_self',
                               category_parent: 'categories_parent'
```

Facebook Event Code Parameter

```
Parameter (3)
content_type: Magazin
category: _removed_
category_parent: _removed_
```

Comment: To track custom events, you need to call the method with first parameter `'trackCustom'` – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking#tracking-custom-events

Comment: Even when using `trackCustom` I'm getting the same problem, for example in my implementation: `fbq('trackCustom', 'customName', JsonObject);` I'm getting `_removed_` fields, even if the Facebook Pixel Helper shows me that the data were successfully sent to Facebook...

Answer (score 0):

When you see your parameters at Activity Panel, then Facebook may remove your parameters if they were converted to hash before they were send OR if they may have confidential data.

But, you are still able to see your events, filter by your parameters, into Facebook Analytics (at the Business Manager) or create your custom conversions by using your knowing data.

Comment: Do you know how Facebook determines "confidential" data?

Comment: Facebook does not let clear about how it determines which data will be removed from the activity panel... but what I have seen since a few weeks ago all datas are being removed. It's more appropriate talk with their support.

Comment: And Facebook Analytics are retired, there are no way to see custom attributes values now. :(